# Instagram: how to catch removal (or archiving) a post?

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api, embedding

I need to show not empty Instagram posts(via Embed js) on my website. But API can not tell about removing or archived posts.

I think that where are any ways.

1. More better way is to catch exception via Embed.js on my frontend and quickly send AJAX reqest to change post status to hidden. But how can I do that?? How to catch?
2. Any ways: using API or parsing. But it can cause more mistakes and will work not quickly. Not convenient way.

Comment: are you getting a dead image link ?

Comment: @krisrak, Embed JS widjet receives link like [https://www.instagram.com/p/BVUhafznx3-/] (for example, deleted post). And we can't trace removing